# Check if post parameters are present

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am currently working on a Magento controller that should handle post requests.

I can check if the request is a POST and extract the parameters but I would like to know if there is a standard way to check if a specific parameter has been passed during the request.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
```

OR

```
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
```

Same thing.

Comment: Null, but you can rule this value through the second param: $email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email', false);